# Nginx reverse proxy not loading/accepting HTTPS requests

Tags: nginx, certbot

I'm using Nginx as Reverse Proxy for my backend running at port 8000. This is my Nginx default configuration:

```
upstream backend {
    least_conn;
    server 127.0.0.1:8000 weight=1 max_fails=0;
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    location / {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        root /var/www/certbot;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;

    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;
    
    location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://backend/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

Note: I've replaced my original domain name with `example.com`.

The server seems to be listening at both ports 80 and 443.
I tried using `proxy_pass` at the HTTP server block, and it works fine without any errors. I've added SSL certificates generated by certbot and separated the server blocks for HTTP and HTTPS.

When I visit my domain the website successfully redirects from HTTP to HTTPS and is stuck at the loading state and ends up with the error: **This site can't be reached**. I tried on different browsers and when I tried to visit the website through a command-line browser (Lynx), this is what it throws back:

```
Looking up example.com
Making HTTP connection to example.com
Sending HTTP request.
HTTP request sent; waiting for response.
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Data transfer complete
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Using example.com
Looking up example.com
Making HTTPS connection to example.com
Alert!: Unable to connect to remote host.

lynx: Can't access startfile example.com
```

When I try to **curl** http://example.com

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.20.2
Date: Sun, 20 Mar 2022 04:22:05 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 169
Connection: keep-alive
Location: https://example.com/

curl: (28) Failed to connect to example.com port 443: Connection timed out
```

And for https://example.com

```
curl: (28) Failed to connect to example.com port 443: Connection timed out
```

Output for **sudo netstat -tulpn | grep :443**

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      8276/docker-proxy   
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      8292/docker-proxy
```

Output for **sudo ufw status**

```
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
Nginx HTTP                 ALLOW       Anywhere                  
Nginx HTTPS                ALLOW       Anywhere                  
Nginx Full                 ALLOW       Anywhere                  
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere                  
OpenSSH                    ALLOW       Anywhere                  
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
Nginx HTTP (v6)            ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
Nginx HTTPS (v6)           ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
Nginx Full (v6)            ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
22 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
OpenSSH (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

I have no idea where I'm going wrong. I tried installing Nginx on my ubuntu ec2, tried different older versions and also tried running Nginx and certbot on docker containers. All of them result in the same error/result.

Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: 1) The trailing slash makes a difference. Try: `proxy_pass http://backend;` 2) Please use **curl -I -L example.com** to debug this and put the output in your question. That command will show the URLs, returned headers, etc.

Comment: Post the output from this command: **sudo netstat -tulpn | grep :443**.

Comment: Do you have a firewall blocking port 443?

Comment: Doesn't looks like it. I'm updating the question with the output from **ufw status**

Comment: There might be an external firewall in AWS - e.g. by a load-balancer or CDN proxy (ELB, CloudFront, etc.)

Comment: Also remove trailing slash in `return 301 https://$host$request_uri`.

Comment: Just checked for any external firewalls in AWS, but there aren't any external firewalls.
Removing the / in ```return 301 https://$host$request_uri`` didn't work

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-security-groups.html